# Scope with different nested joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, scope

My database consists of runners attending sessions

So:

```
class Runner 
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_happenings, through: :attendances, source: :happening
end
```

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :happening
  belongs_to :runner
end
```

```
class Happening
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances, source: :runner
end
```

I want to find all the runners who have *not* attended any happenings in the last 9 weeks. In the runner model I've created a scope `:inactive_for_nine_weeks` :

```
left_joins(:attendances)
  .joins("join happenings on attendances.happening_id = happenings.id")
  .where("attendances.id is null")
  .where("happenings.started_at > ?", 9.weeks.ago)
```

I figure I need to `left_join` on attendances to get the runners that *haven't* got attendances, and then I need to do a regular join on happenings.

I'm getting no results though when I know there should be, so clearly have executed this poorly.

SQL resulting from getting a count from the scope:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "runners" LEFT OUTER JOIN "attendances" ON "attendances"."runner_id" = "runners"."id" join happenings on attendances.happening_id = happenings.id WHERE (attendances.id is null) AND (happenings.started_at > '2023-02-27 08:54:12.460052')
```

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: The reason you're getting no results is that you can't use the old "WHERE x.id is NULL" trick together with additional WHERE clauses on the joined table because the conditions cancel each other out. You would have to move the `happenings.started_at > ?` condition into the join clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward solution in ActiveRecord is to just to do a subquery:

```
class Runner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_happenings, through: :attendances, source: :happening

  # scope is really just syntactic sugar for defining class methods
  # and is really only suited for one liners as multi-line lambas are horrible for readibity
  def self.inactive_since(time = 9.weeks.ago)
    where.not(
      id: Attendance.joins(:happening)
                    .where(happenings: { started_at:  ...time })
                    .select(:runner_id)
    )
  end
end
```

`Runner.inactive_since` gives the following SQL:

```
SELECT "runners".* FROM "runners" 
WHERE "runners"."id" NOT IN (
  SELECT "attendances"."runner_id" FROM "attendances" 
  INNER JOIN "happenings" ON "happenings"."id" = "attendances"."happening_id" 
  AND "happenings"."started_at" > $1
)
```

You could also use EXISTS instead of WHERE IN as a slight optimization (on some DBs).

```
class Runner < ApplicationRecord
  def self.inactive_exists(time = 9.weeks.ago)
    where.not(
      Attendance.joins(:happening)
                .select(1)
                .where.not(Attendance.arel_table[:runner_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                .where(happenings: { started_at: ...time })
                .arel
                .exists
    )
  end
end
```

```
SELECT "runners".* FROM "runners" 
WHERE NOT (
  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM "attendances" 
   INNER JOIN "happenings" ON "happenings"."id" = "attendances"."happening_id" 
   WHERE "attendances"."runner_id" = "runners"."id" 
   AND "happenings"."started_at" < $1
  )
)
```

If you need it you can go for more optimized solutions that are not polyglot like lateral or cross joins or using `COUNT(happenings.*) FILTER (WHERE started_at < ?) = 0` on Postgres. But I would start with the subquery and cross that bridge when you get to it.

Comment: Thanks @max for the really thorough answer. I went with your first solution, although did switch it to a scope. Agree on readability but just made sense to position it with other similar scopes rather than bury it further down the model with other class methods

Answer (score 0):

this is a sql solution for your problem.

You first need to cross join  all runners with all all hapenings to get all combinations.

After that you chekc with LEFT JOIN which runner was at a happening and the rest must be null

```
CREATE tABLe "runners"("id" int)
```

```
INSERT INTO "runners" VALUES (1), (2)
```

```
CREATE tABLe "attendances"(id int,"runner_id" int,happening_id int )
```

```
INSERT INTO "attendances" VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,1)
```

```
CREATE tABLe happenings( id int, started_at timestamp)
```

```
INSERT INTO happenings VALUEs(1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
  FROM ("runners" CROSS JOIN happenings) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "attendances" ON "attendances"."runner_id" = "runners"."id" 
  AND attendances.happening_id = happenings.id 
 WHERE (attendances.id is null) 
  AND (happenings.started_at > '2023-02-27 08:54:12.460052')
```

| count |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/akjJkF4b)